# Unrecognized characters in output

Tags: javascript, api

I'm working on a project, where I'm trying to build a random quote machine using API (I'm using Quotesondesign). Code I have seems to be ok, but I'm getting unrecognized symbols in output. Don't know where it comes from.

So my question: is it something wrong with my code or is it API problem?

My HTML is:

```
<div class="container-fluid row text-center">
  <div class="col-xs-12 well message">
    Your quote
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <button id="getMessage" class="btn btn-primary">
        Get Quote
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

my JS is:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var url = "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1";
    $("#getMessage").on("click", function() {

      $.getJSON(url, function(json) {

        $(".message").html(JSON.stringify(json[0].content + json[0].title));

      });

    });
  });
```

and what I'm getting looks like

```
"
If you never want to be criticized, for goodness’ sake don’t do anything new.
\nJeff Bezos"
```

these " and \n should not be here

Comment: What do you mean by unrecognized symbols in output? Only some characters encoded wrong or is the whole output jibberish? Could you post some of it?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Sorry, just updated my question with an example

Comment: Are  `json[0].content` and `json[0].title` strings?

Comment: Why are you calling `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @melpomene well, thank you for this question! turned out I misunderstood this method. Since I got rid of it, everything works OK! 

and sorry for stupid questions, I'm just a beginner

Comment: THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED

Comment: If @HubertGrzeskowiak answer solves your question, please mark it with a green check.

Answer (score 2):

The API contains HTML tags and escaped newline chars. The quotes come from your `stringify`.

See yourself:
http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1

You can get rid of the HTML and special chars using jQuery like this:

```
var content = $(json[0].content).text();
var title = $(json[0].title).text();
```